# Do static websites store cookies?

Tags: cookies, static, hosting, web-deployment, user-permissions

I am developing a static website and I will deploy it using a hosting service.
I am wondering whether the website will store cookies once deployed (perhaps set by the hosting service), and if and how I should ask users for permission since I have no backend but only frond-end html/css pages.

Answer (score 3):

If there is only HTML and CSS then it stores no cookies. But if you have some javascript code in your website then you can use javascript to store cookies for remembering things. But for a simple HTML and CSS website cookies have no benefit to you and you can't access them.

Comment: Cookies can also be stored using Http header set-cookie, no javascript is required
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

Comment: Yes they can be stored. But by default a basic HTML/CSS website doesn't store them unless added through other ways one being in the Http Header.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! My concern is the European GDPR. If I don't store any cookies and the hosting website does, should I still ask for user permission to store cookies?