# Is there a way to omit cookies with jekyll static site generation?

Tags: html, cookies, jekyll

I know it sounds like a silly question but as the title states I was wondering if I could omit cookies all together with jekyll/webrick.

Web search only shows the implementation of consent banners. But as I hate cookie consent banners myself I was wondering if I could somehow achieve this with plain html or a jekyll config, as I generate the page using jekyll.

I was expecting jekyll config giving the option to somehow be able to omit cookies.

kind regards and happy new year
mitvitaminen

<s>EDIT SAYS: so I found out my page when just static html is generated does not set a cookie at all per default. [Does static web page store cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65341507/do-static-websites-store-cookies)</s>

EDIT SAYS: I found that a firefox addon did set this cookie so everything is good.